# Flask session does not JSON serialize cookie

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask, python-2.6

I'm using Flask's session which sets a signed cookie header in the response.

```
from flask import session
```

This sets a cookie named session with `a = 1`.

```
a = session.get('a', None)
session['a'] = 1
return jsonify(a = a)
```

The `jsonify` in the code is just to show that the cookie is being read at the next request, and it is. This is the response to the second request

```
{
  "a": 1
}
```

I need to read the cookie at the client. So I want it to be JSON encoded. This is the Set-Cookie header in the response

```
Set-Cookie: session=eyJhIjoxfQ.BeUPPQ.Al5bwLzcAsN2f15mdREzhGWP1uc; HttpOnly; Path=/
```

It is not JSON serialized.

Flask version is 0.10.1. Since version 0.10 it uses session from [`itsdangerous`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/sessions.py) which main advantage is to JSON serialize the cookies in instead of the Pickle serialization used before.

What am I missing? Flask version is 0.10.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've misunderstood the format of the default Flask session implementation. The `session` object produces cryptographically signed JSON that is then (optionally) compressed and then base64-encoded to store session values making sure that a client cannot tamper with the values stored in it. In your case no compression was applied (compression is only applied if this reduces the final output size).

This is change from the previous format using `pickle` to limit the damage an attacker can do if the server-side secret was compromised (see a [blog post of mine](http://www.zopatista.com/plone/2007/11/09/one-cookie-please/) why `pickle` can be dangerous).

In other words, all Flask did is swap out the serializer, from `pickle` to an extended tagged JSON format, but the pre-existing cryptographic signature and compression has been left in place.

As such that format is not really suitable for decoding again on the client side (you'd have to decode the base64, possibly decompress the data, split out the signature, and you may have to interpret the extra type tagging). You could switch the session implementations for that but that is very much not recommended.

If you want to share data with the client-side, you could just embed data into page in a `<script>` block with `var session_data = {{data|tojson|safe}};`, or set a separate cookie with the data.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: Removed the part about the `jsonify` then; the rest still stands.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why do flask [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#sessions) suggest that the secret key is only used for signing the data, and not for encryption: _What this means is that the user could look at the contents of your cookie but not modify it, unless they know the secret key used for signing_? Is it a mistake in the documentation, a recent change, or something I misunderstand?

Comment: @max: this answer is indeed misleading, I'll update it. The cookie is cryptographically signed and compressed.

Comment: @max: updated; in this specific case only base64 encoding is applied; there is a `{"a":1}` JSON document in that value, followed by a `\x00` null byte and the signature.